# predict.glm on a valid model returning NULL

Tags: r, dplyr, predict, forcats

I want to use `predict.glm` to return predictions using the same dataset used to train the original model, but I keep getting `NULL` as my result. I have a valid model, with no rows deleted due to missing values.

My code has many variables and the project is a bit sensitive in nature, so I try to reproduce my issue using a toy example. However, as I am unsure of what is causing my problem, I have been unable to reproduce any `NULL` outputs using `glm.predict(object, type = "response)`. It is my hope that someone with prior experience with this problem will be able to recommend solutions.

```r
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)


mod1 <- glm(status ~ 
              state + sex + diag + death + T.categ + age,
            family = "binomial", data = Aids2)
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#Below is caused because `death` has values that yield a status of "D" 100% of #time

head(predict.glm(mod1, type = "response"))
#> 1 2 3 4 5 6 
#> 1 1 1 1 1 1

#removing `death` as predictor

mod2 <- glm(status ~ 
              state + sex + diag + T.categ + age,
            family = "binomial", data = Aids2)
head(predict.glm(mod2, type = "response"))
#>         1         2         3         4         5         6 
#> 0.4690554 0.4758433 0.9820719 0.9884703 0.9292926 0.9333818
```

I am unsure what conditions would cause the above calls to produce `NULL` as the result for `predict.glm` as I have specified it. The results in the code are what I wish to get, but in my actual project, I get `NULL` even though it has returned proper values for me in the past. I realize this isn't a great reproducible example, but I cannot provide details about my actual data. I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** In my original problem, not the toy example above, I was wrapping `glm()` with `summary()`. The solution was to ensure that my `object` argument to `predict.glm` was the general linear model itself, not the summary. I had been careless and assumed that the summary of `glm` would be an equivalent class to `glm` itself.

```r
#same as mod1, but wrapping in summary()

mod3 <- summary(glm(status ~ 
                      state + sex + diag + death + T.categ + age,
                    family = "binomial", data = MASS::Aids2))
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

head(predict.glm(mod3, type = "response"))
#> NULL

mod4 <- summary(glm(status ~ 
                      state + sex + diag + T.categ + age,
                    family = "binomial", data = MASS::Aids2))

head(predict.glm(mod4, type = "response"))
#> NULL
```

I appreciate those who took the time and tried to troubleshoot my question.